# Devolver una cadena u otra dependiendo de valor booleano

Tags: php, woocommerce

Tengo una variable en PHP que antes me funcionaba:

```
<?php $stock = ( $product->is_in_stock() )? 'in-stock' : 'out-stock' ; ?>
```

Ahora que estoy usando javascript solo puedo poner esto:

```
'stock'      =>  $product->is_in_stock(),
```

Y me da como resultado `true` o `false` en WooCommerce. Pero lo que quiero es que me de como resultado así como antes: `true` equivaldría a "in-stock" y `false` a "out-stock" como se puede apreciar en la variable en PHP.

¿Cómo tendría que hacer para pasarlo a JavaScript?

Comment: Hola Eduardo Rafael, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione el codigo es este:

```
'stock'      =>  ( $product->is_in_stock() )? 'in-stock' : 'out-stock',
```